# Inequality featuring minimum value

Tags: inequality

**Problem:** It is known that for all real numbers $p, q, r$, the inequality
$$|(p-q)(q-r)(p-r)(p+q+r)|\leq z(p^2+q^2+r^2)^2$$
holds. Find the smallest real number $z$.

**My attempt:** Note that $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$. Therefore, we may write the left-hand side as
$$|(p-q)(q-r)(p-r)(p+q+r)|=\sqrt{\left[(p-q)(q-r)(p-r)(p+q+r)\right]^2}=\sqrt{(p-q)^2(q-r)^2(p-r)^2(p+q+r)^2}$$
By AM-GM inequality,
$$\begin{aligned}\sqrt{(p-q)^2(q-r)^2(p-r)^2(p+q+r)^2}&\leq\sqrt{\left[\frac{(p-q)^2+(q-r)^2+(p-r)^2+(p+q+r)^2}{4}\right]^4}\\
&=\left[\frac{3(p^2+q^2+r^2)}{4}\right]^2\\
&=\frac{9}{16}\left(p^2+q^2+r^2\right)^2.\end{aligned}$$
Hence, $z=\frac{9}{16}$

But, my solution is marked incorrect. Does using the AM-GM inequality doesn't really minimize $z$?

Comment: You proved that $9/16$ is an upper bound for $z$, but you haven't shown that $9/16$ is the _least_ upper bound for $z$. To see that $9/16$ is _not_ the answer, just consider the conditions for $AM-GM$ to yield equality.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277950